# Why i can't make proper login

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication

i already made a sign up form and everything goes well.
Now i'm trying to do login and i don't succeed.

log1.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>RegPage</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action ="log2.php" method="post">
email: <input type="text" name ="email">
<br/>
password: <input type="password" name="password">

<input type = "submit" value = "insert">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

log2.php

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";  
$password = "";  
$databasename = "pilot"; 

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$databasename);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$comparepass="SELECT password FROM dbinvestor where email=@email";

if ($comparepass==$password)
{
  echo 'logged in !';
}
else
{
    echo '      oops';
}

header ("refresh:10;url=log1.html");

?>
```

DB:
[DB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRYtU.png)

no matter what i instert in textbox the output is alway :

> connect successfully       oops

Why it always "go" to the else also if the password and email are correct ?

Comment: You don't execute any query, let alone fetching results from it. All you do is assigning the **string** `"SELECT password FROM dbinvestor where email=@email"` to `$comparepass`.

Comment: @stickybit why not ? He entered email and password. I search in db the what the real password of the email, and than compare the password he entered to the real password. If there is a match, i write " looged in". Didn't i do it ?

Comment: No you don't "search in db". You're just assigning a string literal to a variable.

Comment: You're comparing the SQL Query string with the password, not any result of these query, because you aren't running the query. You need to execute the query first, get the result to a variable and then, compare it. Check [mysqli query doc](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) for more information about running queries against db.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a SQL query but you don’t actually run it against your database...

```
$comparepass="SELECT password FROM dbinvestor where email=@email";

if ($comparepass==$password)
{
    echo 'logged in !';
}
```

You need to execute the query and fetch the result to compare it with the posted value. Here is bit of code that demonstrates how to proceed, using bind parameters (disclaimer : you seem to be storing clear password in database... just don’t).

```
$sql="SELECT 1 FROM dbinvestor where email=? and password=?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if (!$result) {
    echo 'error: ' . $conn->errno . ' - ' . $conn->error)
} else {
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo 'logged in !';
    } else {
        echo '      oops';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why im not run it against my db ? I took from the db thw password of the email someonw entered. Then i compare the password he wrote to the real password, no ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$comparepass="SELECT * FROM dbinvestor where email='$email' and password='$password'";
$compare_exe=$this->conn()->query($comparepass);  //use your db link
$num_rows=$compare_exe->num_rows;  //get row counter, if exist will return 1 else 0
if($num_rows>0){
echo 'logged in !';
}else{
echo 'opps';

}
```